# how can i implement paging in asp.net like part of "Popular on eBay" in ebay site?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have some items and i want display those in a little and limit div element. those items received from a web service and i want 2 or 3 items display in a time, and exist next and previous button for moving in items (paging). like "Popular on eBay" in ebay site?

i think this can be implement by jquery, any idea?

please help me

Comment: yes, you an definitely do it, but the question is a little broad. Are you looking for actual code or just some general pseudocode ideas?

Comment: yes i know, i forget use paging word in my question, i am sorry

Comment: @picus : yes i want implement actual code

Answer (score 1):

- jquery can allow you to update the div to display the data you want.
- jquery templates can help you format
  the display
- ajax and webservices or page methods
  will help get you the data to display

plentiful demo's exist for all three. If you run into an issue post some code samples of what you have tried and what specific issues you are running into.

Comment: thanks Cos Callis. can you give me a link of a demo and sample code for this case?

Comment: jquery template http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/ will get you most of the way there.
jquery/templating and pagination demo: http://jimfrenette.com/content/2011/02/jquery-mssql-pagination-and-data-templates/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done in jQuery, but the idea behind paging is preventing all of the data to be returned from the server at once.  Otherwise, you are simply hiding data you've already retrieved -- which unless you have a design issue, really doesn't help either party (client/server).  A better solution would be to use jQuery to limit the number of elements returned from the server, based on some locally stored paging variable(s).

Hypothetical answer for a hypothetical question.  If you need additional assistance on how to do it, post some code or a solid concept that you are attempting to retrieve.

Comment: thanks George, yes my data retrieved from server once. but i want this action done in client side. thanks for hypothetical answer, you assume i want implement part of "Popular on eBay" in ebay site, so my items include image, name and price